# How to balance MUC processes in an ejabberd cluster

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

We have an ejabberd cluster with about 700,000 persistent chat rooms. The problem we are facing is that starting the first node of the cluster takes about 1 hour as the Erlang processes for all the rooms are started on that node.

Even after the cluster is initialized and we have say 4 nodes running, the MUC processes aren't balanced across the nodes. There can be a node using 90% of it's memory and another node using 5%.

Is there a way to start multiple nodes of a cluster at once so that the MUC load is spread evenly from the beginning and the startup is faster?

Can anyone suggest a solution for balancing the MUC processes between the cluster nodes?

The way it works now is obviously not scalable, because as the number of rooms grows, we need more and more RAM on the first node that is started in the cluster and also, the startup time increases.

Many thanks, 
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current ejabberd Community Edition there is no such feature. You would need a customized MUC module to match your specific large number of rooms requirement. It is more that load balancing the MUC across the cluster. You need to aggressively optimize for RAM for large scale, at the expense of storage and CPU.

Answer (score 0):

You can load MUC rooms dynamically.Whenever required at that time only you start the room with old options(persistent room means start room with old configuration).

Using this mechanism both problems will be resolved:
1) Ejabberd Starting time(Not starting any MUC rooms since it is on need basis)
2) Load balancing (Because if first requests for that room goes to other node then room will be created there.

Comment: Hey Girdhar - Can you explain this in more detail? Is that a configuration option I missed somewhere, or a customization you made to the module?

Comment: What i am saying is that while creating a room just check that that room is already exist in db or not ? If it exists in db(persistent room) then use those room config otherwise create new room.Alwasys destroy room when there is no participant.                                                                There is no configuration as such.You have to change module for that.